Insert hyperlink to text and jump to next slide in PowerPoint slide using Open XML?
I want to add hyper link to text to move to next slide in same ppt file.
I have added below code but it not works, it gives repair message:
using (PresentationDocument presentationDoc = PresentationDocument.Open(DestinationFile, true))
{
    PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDoc.PresentationPart;
    SlideIdList ObjSlideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
    SlideId ObjslideId = ObjSlideIdList.ChildElements[1] as SlideId;
    string strSlideRelId = ObjslideId.RelationshipId;
    SlidePart ObjSlidPart = presentationDoc.PresentationPart.GetPartById(strSlideRelId) as SlidePart;       
    var table = ObjSlidPart.Slide.Descendants<drawing.Table>().FirstOrDefault();
    var rows = table.Elements<drawing.TableRow>();
    var Row = rows.ElementAt(0);
    var Cell = Row.Elements<drawing.TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
    var textBody = Cell.Elements<drawing.TextBody>().FirstOrDefault();
    var paragraph = textBody.Elements<drawing.Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
    var run = paragraph.Elements<drawing.Run>().FirstOrDefault();
    SlidePart targetSlidePart = presentationPart.SlideParts.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    var targetSlideId = ObjSlideIdList.ChildElements[1] as SlideId;
    string relationshipId = targetSlideId.RelationshipId;
    var hyperlinkRelationship = ObjSlidPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(targetSlidePart.Uri, true);
    drawing.HyperlinkOnClick hyperlinkOnClick1 = new drawing.HyperlinkOnClick() { Id = relationshipId, Action = "ppaction://hlinksldjump"  };
    run.RunProperties.Append(hyperlinkOnClick1);
}

